# How to show a file explorer window in electron app, where the user can select a particular folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, microsoft-file-explorer

I want to pop open a file explorer window in Electron app using React and have a user select a particular folder and then capture the filepath they select, for further processing.

Is there a way to implement the above requirement and any leads would be really helpful .

Comment: Use [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog).

Comment: Yes as Arkellys indicates, it's would be a good idea to have a look to the docs. Don't forget that as you intend to implement functionality which interfer with the Os this should be done in your main process.

Answer (score 2):

Using ***electron dialogs***, *file explorer* can be added in *electron app*.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const {dialog} = window.require("electron").remote;

dialog.showOpenDialogSync({
properties: [
          'openFile', 
          'openDirectory']
      })
```

*Some useful resources:*

- [dialog | Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog)
- [How to choose , read, save, delete or create a file with Electron Framework - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQZEymiWFh8)